# How to display value of a cell on mouse over/hover

Tags: ng-grid

Is there an easy way to display the text value of a cell on mouse over/hover. Something similar to tooltip effect or html's `title` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I found it and the solution is easy. Just add `cellTooltip: true` to the field specified in your column definition (`columnDefs`).